# Need to prevent altering a purchased program when Microsoft does monthly updates

Tags: windows

I purchased a Bible program some time ago. They have sold the rights to another company. This company has completely changed its format, but has allowed the original program I bought to continue to run until the following happens:

"Right now, Wordsearch Bible is still available and should continue to run for some time, but hard to say how long exactly. Logos is not providing any further updates or support for it so when your computer eventually runs into issues with it, which will likely happen the next time your computer runs an operating system update once or twice, support will not be available."

Is there a way to lock down any changes that any updates might make to it so that it continues to function properly?
Thx

Comment: Windows updates should not affect third-party programs, as they only deal with updates to the OS system files and third-party drivers. It is possible for a Windows update to cause issues with a driver, but not with third-party software. _(It sounds like fear-mongering to force customers to update their software, especially when older programs can be run in Compatability mode)_

Comment: At some point, Windows Feature Updates will uninstall non-compliant software. Until then it is fine.

Comment: @JW0914 - it will happen eventually, but it 'depends'… it depends so much that it's simpler for the originating company to simply deny all responsibility.

Comment: @Tetsujin How, as Compatability Mode usually works for older programs?

Comment: Well, the same as happens with anything… eventually that isn't enough. It might take a year, or ten, but it will happen "one day". Personally if it was vital it keep on working, I'd hide it away in a hardened VM. I learned this the hard way. As a pro audio engineer/producer I recorded one album in 2006. The record company wanted a remix/master 10 years later. Even with the support of all the software companies still in business then, we could not re-create the environment required to achieve this. The solution for future projects was to literally store the computer with the project.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer here is… **No.**

As you will never know *which* update may break it, then you would have to prevent all updates [not possible on Windows Home, only Pro] or you would need to use an OS for which there were no further updates ever - e.g.Windows 7, with all the security issues that would entail.